# Rails controller authenticate except json or rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails 3.2 app using `gem 'devise'`.

I would like to authenticate the user in the applications controller - except if it's a rest interface using json.

These didn't work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :rest
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, unless: :api_request?

  def api_request?
    request.format.json?
  end
end
```